# calling url or webservice in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a requirement as follows

**READ**: Hit url and get data(any URL)

**PROCESS**: Need to process response data and set to java object

**WRITE** : Insert data into mysql Database.

I have gone through many examples in SO and and out side SO but I am not clear.I am newbie for spring batch.Can some one please give any example or any website I can get an example for this ?

Is there any reader provided or does we need to write any custom reader ?

Comment: Here is an example of a Reader reading from an URL : https://github.com/mminella/Pro-Spring-Batch-source-code/blob/master/statement-job/src/main/java/com/apress/springbatch/statement/reader/UrlReader.java

Answer (score 0):

Spring Bath provided `ItemReaderAdapter` to invoke a business logic that calls the web service. Using the ItemReaderAdapter, delegates the reading of input to a configured method of a POJO.

ItemReaderAdapter implementation out-of-the-box, they were not restartable since they don't implements ItemStream. So if any of you wants to use ItemReaderAdapter with restartable feature implement `ItemStream`.

```
public class CustomItemReaderAdapter<T> extends AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator<T> implements ItemReader<T>, ItemStream {
 ...
```

And, bean definition in xml:

```
 <bean id="MyReader" class="xxx.yyy.adapters.CustomItemReaderAdapter">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="someAdapter" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="next" />       
 </bean>
```